# Connotation of "significant" or "considerable"

Tags: differences, adjectives, connotation

I know that they are interchangeable and mean nearly the same. But which of them has a stronger connotation in emphasizing the extent or importance more than the other? Or are they on the same level?

Comment: Personally I think "signficiant" is a slightly stronger word.

Comment: @Joachim: I agree with you, but I'm not so sure it's a considerable difference :^)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the context. In technical writing, we are *very* careful with our use of the word *significant*. We only use it when a number (some study result, for example) is statistically significant (with a certain *p* value, for example).

Even in nontechnical writing, though, I would say *significant* has a more technical, exact feel to it than *considerable* does. *Considerable* feels like a "guesstimate."